# Creating a simple label that switches text when tapped in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Swift 4.0 iOS 11.x
Just when you think your getting the hang of things, you realise you missed something critical. Wanted to create a label that changed itself when you tapped it. Created this sub class of label.

```
import UIKit

class TapText: UILabel {

private var changableValues: String = "NESW"
private var currentPosition:Int = 0

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    print("required ")
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  Selector(("tapFunction:")))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

required override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
     print("required override")
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  Selector(("tapFunction:")))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapped")
    self.text = String(Array(changableValues)[currentPosition])
    if currentPosition < changableValues.count {
        currentPosition += 1
    } else {
        currentPosition = 0
    }
}

}
```

Which I thought would work. As Nilish just pointed out I forgot to add userInteractive, but when I do I get a crash.

> 2018-03-12 11:14:40.283502+0100 Blah[952:382749] -[Blah.TapText
>   tapFunction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111a57700
>   2018-03-12 11:14:40.285213+0100 QRCodeReader[952:382749] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Blah.TapText tapFunction:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111a57700'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x184633164 0x18387c528 0x184640628 0x18dfae188 0x184638b10 0x18451dccc 0x18e28aca4 0x18e28f298
>   0x18dd67a14 0x18dc1eb50 0x18e278b08 0x18e278678 0x18e2777d4
>   0x18dc1ce5c 0x18dbede7c 0x18e54330c 0x18e545898 0x18e53e7b0
>   0x1845db77c 0x1845db6fc 0x1845daf84 0x1845d8b5c 0x1844f8c58
>   0x1863a4f84 0x18dc515c4 0x100887c3c 0x18401856c) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

--- added the _  bar and @objc directive, now works... looks like this...

```
required override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
     print("fcuk12032018 required override")
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(tapFunction))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func tapFunction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("fcuk12032018 tapped")
    self.text = String(Array(changableValues)[currentPosition])
    if currentPosition < changableValues.count - 1 {
        currentPosition += 1
    } else {
        currentPosition = 0
    }
}
```

THANKS Nitish!

Comment: You don't seem to have set userInteraction to true anywhere.

Comment: Yes, your right Nilish!!

Comment: On the crash issue - try setting function as func tapFunction(_sender: UITapGestureRecognizer). And set the selector using #selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `userInteraction` to `true` in initialiser. Then `UILabel` will respond to gestures.
**On the crash issue :**
Try setting function as `func tapFunction(_sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)`. And set the selector using **#selector**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed the *userInteractionEnabled* in your code. 
You could add it in your viewController like this :

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet private var myLabel: TapText!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Or directly in your custom class :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    print("required ")
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  Selector(("tapFunction:")))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```